# My images show below the content div and not in it

Tags: html, css

http://img.ctrlv.in/img/17/03/25/58d64289941a7.png

As the title says. I'm really helpless.

If I remove float tags from the css, it's exactly as I want it - but the images aren't next to each other. -> http://img.ctrlv.in/img/17/03/25/58d6444491235.png

Thanks in advance.

Comment: include html and css , or else it is difficult to get any answer

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code - post code as text here.

Comment: It wouldn't let me paste it here because of the length and I can't edit the post because there's something wrong with formatting.

Comment: edit your question and paste the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is called "clearing floats". You need to put a new element after the images, and the add `clear: both;` to the new element's CSS.

Here is an example, the important parts are `<div class="clear"></div>` and

```
.clear {
  clear: both;
}
```

---

```css
.content {
  background-color: grey; /* only for demonstration */
}

.img-placeholder {  /* only for demonstration */
  height: 100px;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 10px;
  float: left;
}

.clear {      /* this is the important part */
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="img-placeholder"></div>
  <div class="img-placeholder"></div>
  
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's all perfect now!

Comment: I'm glad to know it helped!

Answer (score 0):

Try to give,

```
.obsah{
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: the reason is because of floating element.

Comment: .obsah{ display: block; overflow: hidden;}

Comment: doesn't seem to do anything